# Oauth 2 for multiple clients with different REST APIs

Tags: api, rest, oauth, uml, microservices

My question is about a good way how to model an account service above multiple profiles that are actually within multiple REST services.

Imagine you have a profile on platform A for chatting and writing and doing some stuff within a community. Further you have a second profile on another platform B where you can buy things for platform A.
You have two profiles within one ecosystem that I want to connect under one account. So what I came up with is to do it via Oauth 2 as the following:

The part until get client should be a typical oauth 2 more or less afterwards i tried to fetch the switch between accounts.

[image: UML scratch]

**Are there any ways that are more proper for it or is this one capable for the task?**

**Would you improve something or are there security problems?**

Comment: The only thing at first hand would be to use dashed lines for return message where appropriate. Also I miss the object life. Else it looks fine.

Comment: Can you clarify this part "need an build in miniservice for keeping the connection or handle the Requests to the Auth Server"? Why would the client need to keep a connection? Can't you simply have the OAuth key and reuse it asynchronously? Even if the protocol you are using is stateful, why would the client need to handle a conversation initiated by another peer?

Comment: this part got actually obsolete because as you mentioned there is no need for that kind of connection - that was actually a lack of understanding